# Incompatibility between NiceTabular Blocks and Setcellgapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nicematrix

Nicematrix is a powerful package and I want to give all my Thanks to F.Pantigny for his work. I just started to use it and I'm very pleased with a various amount of possibilities that this package offers. But I have an issue when using it with `\Block`s.
Please be kind and don't mind the `\sf` and the `\small` that are misbehaviour but irrelevant for the question I ask.

I want to fit three lines into a cell in a very simple tabular. But I also want to use `\makegapedcells` to enlarge the rows.

#### Without Makegapedcells

I tried two ideas:

- Making a block out of one cell (which I assume is cheating) with `\Block{1-1}`.
- Making blocks of three cells by column with `\Block{3-1}`.

Both worked fine.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=0.8cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.3cm, right=1.3cm}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    \sf  
    
    %--------------------- Biscuits 
    \small
    
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|W{c}{3mm}|W{c}{15mm}|*{8}{W{c}{13mm}|}}[code-before =\rowcolor{gray!20}{1},code-before =\columncolor{gray!20}{1}]
        \hline  
        & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I\\
        \hline
        1 & & Lundi & Mardi & Mercredi & Jeudi & Vendredi & Samedi & Dimanche & Total \\
        \hline
        2 & \Block{1-1}{Nombre de\\biscuits\\vendus} & 324 & 240 & 310 & 204 & 318 & 386 & 468 & \\
        \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}
    
    \vspace*{1cm}
    
        %--------------------- Biscuits  2
    
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|W{c}{3mm}|W{c}{15mm}|*{8}{W{c}{13mm}|}}[code-before =\rowcolor{gray!20}{1},code-before =\columncolor{gray!20}{1}]
        \hline  
        & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I\\
        \hline
        1 & & Lundi & Mardi & Mercredi & Jeudi & Vendredi & Samedi & Dimanche & Total \\
        \hline
        \Block{3-1}{2} & \Block{3-1}{Nombre de\\biscuits\\vendus} & \Block{3-1}{324} & \Block{3-1}{240} & \Block{3-1}{310} & \Block{3-1}{204} & \Block{3-1}{318} & \Block{3-1}{386} & \Block{3-1}{468} & \Block{3-1}{}\\
        & & & & & & & & & \\
        & & & & & & & & & \\
        \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Without makegapedcells]

#### With Makegapedcells

Now I want to use `\setcellgapes{5pt}` to enlarge the rows because I find them too thin. I tried exactly the same two options.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=0.8cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.3cm, right=1.3cm}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\makegapedcells
\setcellgapes{5pt}

\begin{document}
    \sf  
    
    %--------------------- Biscuits 
    \small
    
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|W{c}{3mm}|W{c}{15mm}|*{8}{W{c}{13mm}|}}[code-before =\rowcolor{gray!20}{1},code-before =\columncolor{gray!20}{1}]
        \hline  
        & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I\\
        \hline
        1 & & Lundi & Mardi & Mercredi & Jeudi & Vendredi & Samedi & Dimanche & Total \\
        \hline
        2& \Block{1-1}{Nombre de\\biscuits\\vendus} & 324 & 240 & 310 & 204 & 318 & 386 & 468 & \\
        \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}
    
    \vspace*{1cm}
    
        %--------------------- Biscuits  2
    
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|W{c}{3mm}|W{c}{15mm}|*{8}{W{c}{13mm}|}}[code-before =\rowcolor{gray!20}{1},code-before =\columncolor{gray!20}{1}]
        \hline  
        & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I\\
        \hline
        1 & & Lundi & Mardi & Mercredi & Jeudi & Vendredi & Samedi & Dimanche & Total \\
        \hline
        \Block{3-1}{2} & \Block{3-1}{Nombre de\\biscuits\\vendus} & \Block{3-1}{324} & \Block{3-1}{240} & \Block{3-1}{310} & \Block{3-1}{204} & \Block{3-1}{318} & \Block{3-1}{386} & \Block{3-1}{468} & \Block{3-1}{}\\
         & & & & & & & & & \\
         & & & & & & & & & \\
        \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}
        
\end{document}
```

And here is what happens (note that in the second table, the numbers are changing their positions every time I compile the code, but never go to their expected place).

[image: With Makegapedcells]

#### Question

What did I do wrong? Is there a way to manage the height of rows without using `\makegapedcells`, and even better, is there a way to bypass this apparent incompatibility to let me have into the same document old fashioned tables and NiceTabular ones ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remark: Making `\Block` of one cell is not cheating in `nicematrix`. It's documented as possible and there is a syntactic shorcut for that: `\Block{}{smth}` stands of `\Block{1-1}{smth}`.

Comment: Thanks François. I just said that I felt it was cheating, but now I can see that it's a valid solution whenever it's needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `nicematrix` package offers a built-in way to increase the row heights using `cell-space-top-limit` and `cell-space-bottom-limit` similar to the commands provided by the `cellspace` package. It's also possible to set both parameters with the key `cell-space-limits`.

Instead of multiple `\Block` commands and manual linebreaks, I suggest using a horizontally centered `m` type column for the second column. Since the text was too wide for the 15 mm wide column I slightly increased the column width to 17 mm. I also replaced `\sf` with `\sffamily`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=0.8cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.3cm, right=1.3cm}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    \sffamily 
    \small
    
    \begin{NiceTabular}{W{c}{3mm}m[c]{17mm}*{8}{W{c}{13mm}}}[cell-space-limits=5pt, hvlines]
     \CodeBefore
        \rowcolor{gray!20}{1}
        \columncolor{gray!20}{1}
     \Body
        & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I\\
        1 & & Lundi & Mardi & Mercredi & Jeudi & Vendredi & Samedi & Dimanche & Total \\
        2 & Nombre de biscuits vendus & 324 & 240 & 310 & 204 & 318 & 386 & 468 & \\
    \end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @leandriis. Seems that I was looking for something too complex, when the easy solution was just in front of me.

Comment: @SebGlav: I just edited my answer to include another simplification. The key `hvlines` can automatically draw all relevant vertical and hirizontal lines for you, so ne need for any `|` or `\hline`.